# I am 58 years old, can I pursue a PhD?

Tags: phd, age

I am interested in doing a PhD in Industrial Engineering and Operations Research at any of the premier American Universities. I have a postgraduate degree in Industrial Engineering from Indian Institute of Technology, Kharagpur, India, which I completed in 1983. I have about 30 years of working experience in India as an Industrial Engineer.

Comment: I am presently working as Asst. Prof at Muffakham Jah college of Engineering and Technology at Hyderabad for the past four years.

Comment: I started my PhD at age 52, also with 30 years industry experience. I don't think the few extra years should make much difference, but the most reliable way to find out is to apply.

Comment: During my PhD study, one of my friends was 50 years old. He successfully completed and defended his PhD thesis in Mechanical Engineering department from Indian Institute of Technology, India this year. However, in India, there may be an issue with age. I suggest you to apply with sponsored candidate by industry or your present employer. I am not sure about other countries.

Answer (score 12):

Well, I was 58 when I applied for the Ph.D. program from which I received my doctorate, so the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly you can. I personally believed that you will not only be competitive, but respected. My advice, apply, apply, and apply.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. It is not your age that matters, but the will to excel. Although rare, there are some who do pursue PhD past 50. I don't see why shouldn't you apply. If you are passionate about your aim, by all means go for it.